# Is there a way to set an Android and IOS app icon to an SVG file using Flutter if so, how?

Tags: flutter, svg, icons

I want to use SVG images to make apps look nice at different sizes in Flutter, but I don't know how or if it can be done. I'm guessing that packages like flutter_svg or svgpath_to_flutter could get the job done. An example of how this would be done be nice tho.

I've tried the flutter_launcher_icons package but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you mean icon for App. Like the icon that shows in playstore??
or do you mean by icons inside the app like home icon or any image inside the app??

Answer (score 0):

I am using svg like a preloader.

```
    import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

// ......

    Widget _buildPreloader() {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.blueGrey,
          child: Center(
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/runnerLogo.svg',
              color: Colors.white,
              width: 40.0,
              height: 40.0,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: I think that would be useful to manage SVG inside the app, but I'm wondering if it's possible to make it the launcher icon.